# How can I align two itemised lists of items in two columns?

Tags: beamer

I would like to list (itemise) some items and visualise them in two different column in Beamer.

I tried in this way:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{image} 
\centering
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.47\textwidth}
            List1 
            \begin{itemize}
              \scriptsize
                \item item1 
                \item item2 
                \item item3
                \item item4
                \item item5
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            List2
           \begin{itemize}
              \scriptsize
                  \item6
                  \item7
           \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
```

Unfortunately it seems not working. I also tried to use Parallel but I had problem to itemise the elements of the two lists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably you can try with `\begin{column}[t]`. Like that, the two columns are top aligned with respect to each other.

Comment: If I make your code compilable and use the `t` option for *both* `\begin{column}` commands, I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjdGU.png If this does not suit your needs, please add a sketch of the desired otput and/or make a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that is closer to your actual document.

Comment: Thanks leandriis. I think the problem could be an image because it does not align perfectly the text. I used `\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{image}
\centering`

Comment: Please make a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question.. With the information you provided so far, it is impossible to guess what you are doing and why it is not working as expected.

Comment: After completing your code fragment to the MWE I obtain expected result: a slide with image horsinatally centered and below it two vertically aligned lists (left with 5 items, right with two) since i consider @leandriis first comment. I have recent beamer and MIkTeX instalation.

Comment: Probably I am doing something wrong because copying and past the same code with leandriis' suggestion, I have an image horizontally entered and below two vertically not aligned list (that one with two elements is below). Thank you anyway for your help. I will try to figure out what is going wrong with the code.